# Save awk output into variable

Tags: unix, awk

My intention is to take the second line and look for the characters after the `.` delimiter. It works like this:

```
prompt> awk -F '.' 'FNR == 2 {print $NF}' file_name.txt
Sam
```

However, I wish to *store* that output in the variable, but its showing an error:

```
prompt> Name= $(awk -F '.' 'FNR == 2 {print $NF}' file_name.txt)
Sam: command not found
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should *not* have a space between `Name=` and `$(awk`. That turns it into a temporary variable assignment for one command, similar to the difference between:

```
name=bob    # sets name to bob
name= bob   # sets name to nothing while running bob
```

In other words, use:

```
prompt> Name=$(awk -F '.' 'FNR == 2 {print $NF}' file_name.txt)
prompt> echo $Name
Sam
```

Comment: $ test23=awk -F '.' 'FNR == 2 {print $NF}' file_name.txt
-ksh: -F: not found [No such file or directory]
$ awk -F '.' 'FNR == 2 {print $NF}' file_name.txt
Sam
$ 


doesnot work!!

Comment: @PiyushAnand, why are you testing something *different* to what I suggested? :-) You're missing the `$()` stuff around the `awk` command. That makes it an attempt to set `test23` to `awk` then run the `-F` command.